# Seemingly no connection to Nginx but website error page successfully loads

Tags: django, nginx, debian, uwsgi

I have an issue going on that has me completely stumped.
I am running a Django Application through Nginx and UWSGI, and a DNS that runs through cloudflare.

When I go the website, I receive the proper website error page (the one set in Django).
However, there are no logs anywhere, not in Django, UWSGI, or Nginx (even regarding access!). I have no idea how this is routing yet failing to log anything and have no idea where to look to change anything.

Just to reiterate:
server: Nginx through UWSGI using a python virtual env |
App type: Django |
DNS provider: Cloudflare |
Logs: None found, but should be propagating if things error |
Error page: Django applications custom error

Will gladly post info or logs if someone points me towards where I should look. We have had this site working properly on a different server using a different OS version (Debian stretch versus our current debian bullseye). Folder names etc have all been copied from there.

** We are running a nonstandard python version, but all research has shown that this should be fine as long as our Virtualenv is setup with the right python version.

Update: After inspecting the network I found it is getting a 521 error, even though nginx/uwsgi are both running

Comment: It's possible your browser is helping you by showing a cached page.  You might try Ctrl-Shift-R to force a refresh.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this a number of times, but still get the same custom error page. Currently reaching out to our cloudflare guy to confirm that there's absolutely no way cloudflare could somehow be showing us the custom error (which there doesn't seem to be as we have a separate cloudflare error page)